# Error CS0029 Cannot implicitly convert type System.Collections.Generic.List to same?

Tags: c#, asp.net, rest, web-services, .net-core

Specs: using ASP.NET Core 7.0.307, on Mac OS Ventura 13.5 Darwin, VS Code 1.81.1

I am getting an error after updating an interface file and using it in a service in order to perform a delete operation with a DTO.

The error is

> ./rpc/Services/CharacterService/CharacterService.cs(129,20): error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type
> 'rpc.Models.ServiceResponse<System.Collections.Generic.List<rpc.DTOs.Character.GetCharacterDTO>>' to
> 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task<rpc.Models.ServiceResponse<System.Collections.Generic.List<rpc.DTOs.Character.GetCharacterDTO>>>' [./rpc/rpc.csproj]

I note that I didn't get this error at all with the previous CRU(D) operations (Create, Read and Update) That I had created with this project.

The DTO declaration, `GetCharacterDTO`, looks like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using rpc.Models.Enums;

namespace rpc.DTOs.Character
{
    // considered to call it GetCharacterResponseDTO.cs
    public class GetCharacterDTO
    {
        public int Id { get; set; } = 1;
        public string Name { get; set; } = "Frodo";

        public string EMail{ get; set; } = "";

        public int Strength { get; set; } = 10;
        public int Defense { get; set; } = 10;
        public int HitPoints { get; set; } = 100;
        public int Intelligence { get; set; } = 10;

        public RpgClass Class { get; set; } = RpgClass.Knight; // this will be and admin or user for generic usage
    }
}
```

which uses an Enum (posted here for reference)

```
using System.Text.Json.Serialization;

namespace rpc.Models.Enums
{
    [JsonConverter(typeof(JsonStringEnumConverter))]
    public enum RpgClass
    {
       Knight = 1,
       Mage = 2,
       Cleric = 3,
       NPC = 4,
       Admin = 10000,
       User =  9999,
    }
}
```

The relevant interface looks like this:

`iCharacterService.cs`:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using rpc.DTOs.Character;
using rpc.Models;

namespace rpc.Services.CharacterService
{
    public interface ICharacterService
    {
      // other valid methods that are ok... then

        // add delete character method to enforce delete functionality
        // no particular errors appear here
        Task<ServiceResponse<List<GetCharacterDTO>>> DeleteCharacter(int id);

    }
}
```

The relevant services that implements `iCharacterService.cs` (`CharacterService.cs`) looks like the following.

Note that I am using the Automapper extension (https://www.nuget.org/packages/AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection/ ) to utilize mapping the model and the respective DTOs. The error occurs at the return statement.

```
global using AutoMapper;

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using rpc.Models;

namespace rpc.Services.CharacterService
{
        // enable list of characters
        private static List<Character> characters = new List<Character>
        {
            new Character(),
            new Character { Id = 2, Name = "Sam" }
        };

        private readonly IMapper _mapper;

        public CharacterService(IMapper mapper)
        {
            _mapper = mapper;
        }

        // other valid methods here for CRU(d) actions ... they work, but the delete method
        // does not work, even though its templated against similar code in this same file 
        // and other examples

        public Task<ServiceResponse<List<GetCharacterDTO>>> DeleteCharacter(int id)
        {
            var serviceResponse = new ServiceResponse<List<GetCharacterDTO>>();
            try
            {
                var character = characters.First(c => c.Id == id);

                if (character is null)
                {
                    throw new Exception($"Character with Id '{id}' not found");
                }
                characters.Remove(character);
                serviceResponse.Data = characters.Select(c => _mapper.Map<GetCharacterDTO>(c)).ToList();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                serviceResponse.Success = false;
                serviceResponse.Message = ex.Message;
            }

            return serviceResponse; // VS code indicates that

            // throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
}
```

VS Code highlights a dialog that displays the following information for the line

```
return serviceResponse
```

and shows this error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'rpc.Models.ServiceResponse<System.Collections.Generic.List<rpc.DTOs.Character.GetCharacterDTO>>' to 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task<rpc.Models.ServiceResponse<System.Collections.Generic.List<rpc.DTOs.Character.GetCharacterDTO>>>'RoslynCS0029
> (local variable) ServiceResponse<List>? serviceResponse
> 'serviceResponse' is not null here.

Not sure how to proceed, I re-entered the code from the ground up with no issues up until the return statement.

To compare, my update method in `CharacterService.cs` runs fine and looks like:

```
public async Task<ServiceResponse<GetCharacterDTO>> UpdateCharacter(UpdateCharacterDTO updatedCharacter)
{
        // update all the properties with new values
        var serviceResponse = new ServiceResponse<GetCharacterDTO>();

        try
        {
            // set character to the character with the matching id
            var character = characters.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Id == updatedCharacter.Id);

            if (character is null)
            {
                //serviceResponse.Success = false;
                //serviceResponse.Message = "Character not found.";
                //return serviceResponse; // or throw an exception

                throw new Exception($"Character with id {updatedCharacter.Id} not found.");
            }

            // options: use automapper to map the updatedCharacter to the character
            // _mapper.Map<Character>(updatedCharacter); // or
            // _mapper.Map(updatedCharacter, character); // but would have to update AutoMapperProfile.cs

            // update the character with the new values
            character.Name = updatedCharacter.Name;
            character.EMail = updatedCharacter.EMail;
            character.Class = updatedCharacter.Class;
            character.Defense = updatedCharacter.Defense;
            character.HitPoints = updatedCharacter.HitPoints;
            character.Intelligence = updatedCharacter.Intelligence;
            character.Strength = updatedCharacter.Strength;
            serviceResponse.Data = _mapper.Map<GetCharacterDTO>(character);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            serviceResponse.Success = false;
            serviceResponse.Message = ex.Message;
        }

        return serviceResponse;
    }
}
```

which runs fine.

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: Your method is returning a `Task<ServiceResponse<GetCharacterDTO>>` but you are not doing any `async` work in there, so just change it to be `ServiceResponse<GetCharacterDTO>`. Closing this as a typo

Answer (score 1):

> Cannot implicitly convert type System.Collections.Generic.List to same?

They are not the same, `ServiceResponse<List<GetCharacterDTO>>` is not `Task<ServiceResponse<List<GetCharacterDTO>>>` which is specified as return type.

You can use `Task.FromResult` for the first snippet:

```
return Task.FromResult(serviceResponse);
```

The `async` version works because it is handled by compiler (which will do all the necessary task wrapping and so on, if you want a deep dive into how and why there are multiple resources in the internet - [How Async/Await Really Works in C#](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/how-async-await-really-works/), [Dissecting the async methods in C#](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/premier-developer/dissecting-the-async-methods-in-c/)).

But since you are not doing any actual async work you can/should just change the return type to `ServiceResponse<List<GetCharacterDTO>>`:

```
public ServiceResponse<List<GetCharacterDTO>> DeleteCharacter(int id)
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: thank you! that works. Can you explain the return statement a little bit more for me ? The FromResult() method simply states 'that it Creates a Task that's completed successfully with the specified result' but not clear what it means with respect to this delete operation context..

Comment: @DJEddieJ _"but not clear what it means with respect to this delete operation context"_ -  can you please elaborate? In short it does is `new Task<TResult>(result)` which results in task with `TaskStateFlags.RanToCompletion` state and the result set to value you have provided. In terms of types there are no particular magic here (compared to the `async` counterpart).

Comment: Thanks for the amended reply, it makes sense now, it was in fact just made me dizzy to take a look at the object types (and forgot the Task part , hence it looked the 'same'. need more coffee and rest). cheers

Comment: @DJEddieJ happens to everybody! Was glad to help. If answer worked for you - feel free to mark it as accepted one ;)